# Pleaseinsertintopreamble in ToC and header

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, titlesec

I wanted to style chapter headings, found out about `titlesec` and  wrote the document like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{crvena}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\definecolor{plava}{rgb}{.204,.353,.541}

\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[display] % shape
{\bfseries\flushright\Huge\color{crvena}} % format
{\ \thechapter} % label
{0.5ex} % sep
{
\vspace{1ex}
} % before-code
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}%
\color{plava}\rule{\textwidth}{2.3pt}
] % after-code

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Лавиринт}
```

After that I wrote some text and finished with:

```
\end{document}
```

The result is fine, as can be seen from the image:

[image]

But the problem is now that there are errors in table of contents:

ToC:

[image]

What has caused `1 [Pleaseinsertintopreamble]` to be written instead of `1 Лавиринт` and how to fix it?

EDIT 1: I tried to use fancyhdr, but got this:

ToC is fine: [image]

but header is not:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem usually is associated to the `utf8x` option to `inputenc` rather than `utf8`.

Comment: Thanks. :)
I've seen that the problem occurs with utf8x, so I was somewhat surprised to see it happen with utf8 as well. If I add \usepackage{fancyhdr}, ToC works fine, but then headers are wrong. I'm new to both fancyhdr and titlesec, so I have no clue what's going on. : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `serbianc` module for `babel` seems to enforce using the `utf8x` option for `inputenc` and the package `ucs` which is, in my opinion, wrong.

A workaround seems to be specifying `utf8x` prior to `utf8`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x,utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}
```

However, I would ask the maintainer of `babel` to remove the setting, leaving the user the choice of what option for `inputenc` to use. And I'd much prefer `utf8`.